# fastest way to gather bits (similar to std::copy_if)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

To clarify, this is what gathering bits means: (in this question's context)

```
size_t gather_bits(size_t source, size_t mask) {
    size_t result = 0, next_bit_index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(size_t) * 8; i++)
        if ((mask >> i) & 1)
            result |= ((source >> i) & 1) << next_bit_index++;
    return result;
}
```

For every on Nth bit in the mask, the Nth bit in the result is set from the source with the index of that Nth bit in the mask. (`result[mask_on_bit] = source[mask_bit_index]`)

The snippet I added is the simplest implementation, but the fastest I found unfortunately, I couldn't come with anything better. Is there anything faster than that? Consider the `mask` to be completely random (so searching for large number of 0s in the mask should not benefit much)

Comment: If you include `limits.h` you can replace your *magic* `8` with the proper `CHAR_BIT` constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gather bits at specific positions into a new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200255/gather-bits-at-specific-positions-into-a-new-value)

Comment: `pext` exists natively on some platforms (it's not always fast)

Comment: @harold this can be possible answer I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider a branchless solution, which can often give significant performance benefits on some architectures.  Something like this:

```
size_t gather_branchless( size_t source, size_t mask )
{
    size_t result = 0, select = 1;
    source &= mask;
    while( source != 0 )
    {
        int used = (mask & 1);
        result |= (source & select);
        select <<= used;
        source >>= !used;
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This completely avoids any branching, except for the loop termination test.  I ran a benchmark of this method using millions of randomly generated values to compare the timings.  Run on a Intel Core i7 2.9GHz compiled with Clang and full optimizations:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| solution     | approx time |
+--------------+-------------+
| txtechhelp   | 1500 ms     |
| yours        | 1400 ms     |
| SGeorgiades  | 1300 ms     |
| branchless   | 600 ms      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

The astute person might notice that my branchless version will terminate early when there are no bits left to combine.  In the interest of fairness, I ran the test with the highest bit always set for both value and mask.  Doing this added another 50 milliseconds onto the result.

So there you have it.  A branchless solution that, at least on the Intel architecture I tested it with, runs at more than twice the speed of yours.  Another benefit of this is that it's easily converted into SIMD if you want to further optimize your code on large datasets.

You can [see my benchmark online](http://ideone.com/CXlI8t) if you would like to play around with other solutions.  Note that it's written in C++, not C.  My tests used `g++ -std=c++11 -O2`.  This was linked with a C object file containing the target functions which was generated with `gcc -O2`.

Comment: Another quick hack at efficiency is simply to dump and compare the assembly. The function loop here consists of 12 instructions, compared to 18 in the nearest competitor. Nicely done. (using `-Ofast` optimization)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be faster, because it only shifts one bit at a time, and the individual calculations (especially the calculation to mask the bit into "result") is much simpler.

```
size_t gather_bits(size_t source, size_t mask) {
    size_t result = 0, next_bit_mask = 1;
    while (value)
    {
        if (mask & 1)
        {
            if (source & 1)
                result |= next_bit_mask;
            next_bit_mask <<= 1;
        }
        mask >>= 1;
        source >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Updated to terminate when value reaches zero, per @paddy's suggestion... good call!

Comment: That depends on the processor, Anthony... on an x86, you are right, but on certain microcontrollers (Philips 82C50 family, for example) it is not. Careful about such blanket statements, when the target platform is not specified.

Comment: I did not expect this solution to be a significant improvement due to the branching cost, but I benchmarked it anyway.  It is marginally better than the original solution, however.  Have a read of my answer for a fairly simple branchless version.  You can find a link to the benchmarking code, if you want to try for something even faster. =)

Comment: @SGeorgiades That's what I love about SO. You always think you know better, but then someone comes in and enlightens you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and posted code are a little confusing.

In your question, you ask that *"for every on Nth bit in the mask, the Nth bit in the result is set from the source with the index of that Nth bit in the mask."* Which I understand to mean that for every bit in `mask` that is a `1`, you set the bit in `result` to the bit in `source` at the index the `1` is set in `mask`.

So as a simple example, if `source` is `106` (binary `0110 1010`) and `mask` is `43` (binary `0010 1011`), the result should be `0010 1010` (decimal `42`); the simplest and quickest way to do this is with a bitwise `AND`, example:

```
size_t gather_bits(size_t source, size_t mask)
{
    return (source & mask);
}
```

But your posted code does not do what you're asking in your question (unless I misunderstand your question). Instead, in your posted code, if the `Nth` bit in `mask` is set, it pushes the `Nth` bit from `source` to the LSB of `result`.

Using the above example, if `source` is `106` and `mask` is `43` then the result would be `0000 1110`.

If this *is* your intent, then you could use static maps of known values (instead of pushing bits around each iteration), example:

```
// assumes a 64-bit architecture
static size_t masks[] = {
    1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,
    2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,
    262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,
    8388608,16777216,33554432,67108864,134217728,
    268435456,536870912,1073741824,2147483648,
    4294967296,8589934592,17179869184,34359738368,68719476736,
    137438953472,274877906944,549755813888,1099511627776,
    2199023255552,4398046511104,8796093022208,17592186044416,
    35184372088832,70368744177664,140737488355328,281474976710656,
    562949953421312,1125899906842624,2251799813685248,4503599627370496,
    9007199254740992,18014398509481984,36028797018963968,72057594037927936,
    144115188075855872,288230376151711744,576460752303423488,1152921504606846976,
    2305843009213693952,4611686018427387904,0x8000000000000000
};

size_t gather_bits(size_t source, size_t mask)
{
    size_t result = 0, next_bit_index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(size_t) * 8; ++i)
        if (mask & masks[i])
            result |= ((source & masks[i]) >> (i - next_bit_index++));
    return result;
}
```

This reduces the bitwise shifts and branching, though if it is *actually* faster would depend on a lot of things, and would require more testing in your environment.

Hope that can help.

Comment: This is slower than all other solutions, including the original.  I have added your result to the benchmarks in my answer.

Comment: @paddy, you're using C++14 on a C subset. Try different compilers with different options .. on my machine, with a C compiler, your code is actually slower than mine :)

Comment: Are you using any optimizations?

Comment: Note, I compiled the test functions in C as a library with gcc (`-O2` optimizations), then linked into my benchmark code.  Same result.

Comment: It's faster, but still comes out about 100ms slower than the original example.  The problem is you still have branching, and you've added a lookup table.  The extra cost might be less if you compile with full loop unrolling, but it doesn't seem to add any benefit, given a much faster and simpler solution exists.

Comment: @paddy .. using full optimizations on both Windows (Visual Studio) and OpenBSD (gcc), this code is faster; additionally, SGeorgiades is faster than your posted code on my machine (even though it has branching) .. chalk it up to another example of "different machines/compilers" :)

Comment: Would you care to post the code you used to benchmark this?  Or did you use mine?  Note that my code was carefully written to prevent the compiler from optimizing assumptions about values or masks into the function calls.  If you use a static mask value, you will have very different results.